sqlsrv_connect returns SSL: The target principal name is incorrect in PHP
I am setting up a new Windows 2022 server to run my PHP sites. When trying to connect to a SQL server using sqlsrv_connect in my PHP site, I get SSL: The target principal name is incorrect. I do not have this problem on my existing Windows 2012 R2 Server. Is this an upgrade issue? A certificate issue?

It turns out I needed to install SQL Server Management Studio for it to make the connection.

It's probably actually a driver which came with it which was needed. Management studio itself is just a guide app, your php code wouldn't need that

Probably correct.

Sorry I meant GUI app, not guide app. Spellcheck!
